# Calling an action method on predefined time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an action method inside a controller class , that do a Sync . currently the user can manually call this action method, by clicking on a button from the view.

But my question is whether I can create a job or bath that runs on the host server let say each 1 hour and call this action method.

Currently I am using form authentication, and i am hosting my asp.net mvc web application on IIS 7

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this.

Refactor the code out of MVC and put it inside a WCF service, configure this service to make use of http://quarts.net/ and setup the schedule to run.  This service can then be hosted inside IIS.

You can also create a Windows Service (NT Service) that makes use of Quartz.Net. This service can then be installed on the production server.

You can create a batch file and use a windows task to fire off an exe that will run the job.

Comment: The typical and easiest method is to just create a console app that will hit the URL, and then set up a Scheduler job on a server that runs that console app as desired.

Comment: @ChrisPratt although easy and typical to do that, I left that out of the choices and opted for refactoring as a proper 3 tier design would see the long running process in a tier lower than the UI. Also as the code was more than likely written too return either a view or data to be displayed in a view, calling it from a unattended console probably doesn't make sense, as no one will be viewing the results

Comment: @3dd can you provide some links which can help me in achieving this ?

Comment: @johnG sure, these will point you in the right direction. Shout if you have any problems. http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/04/10/walkthrough-scheduling-jobs-using-quartz.net-ndash-part-1-what-is.aspx and http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2146/scheduling-a-service-using-quartz. There is also http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/